# Editing Params on Form Submission in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form in my app which on submitting creates `order_params` as follows.

```
{"vendor_number"=>"200", "received_date"=>"2014-08-08", "po_number"=>"aaaa", "order_status"=>"-2", "shop_id"=>"2", "order_number"=>"12953", "shop_number"=>""}
```

And in my create function inside my controller im trying to edit the shop_number like this.

```
def create
    p "------------------"
    order_params[:shop_number] = 4
    p order_params
    p order_params[:shop_number]
    p "------------------"
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to '/purchase', notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

But order_params[:shop_number] is still not getting updated.. Please help. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three easiest ways:

One is:

You may set the shop number is your form by using hidden field.

```
f.hidden_field :shop_number, value: (shop_number_variable || 4) #what ever you want
```

Second is:

As described by nithin.

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@order.shop_number = (shop_number_variable || 4) #what ever you want
@order.save
```

Third is:

You may use before_filter. like `before_save` or `before_create` etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@order.shop_number = 4
if @order.save 
......
```